# Prolog counting using s(0) and p(0)

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I am having some issues with  a part of my revision for my prolog exam.

I need to create a recursive statement that will be called simplify/2. An example use would be

```
simplify(s(p(s(0))),Z)
```

which would result in `Z` being s(0). S stands for successor and P predecessor. 
So:
`s(0)` is 1, 
`s(s(0))` is 2 and `p(0)` is -1 etc. 
and 
`p(s(p(p(0))))` would be `p(p(0))`.

The code I initially had was

```
check(s(0),s(0)).
check(s(X),s(0)) :- check(X,s(s(0))).
check(p(X),s(0)) :- check(X,0).
```

But this clearly doesn't work as the second part needs to be kept as a variable that is added on to itself during the recursive call. I'll have another look at it in around 30 minutes because my head is fried at the moment.

Comment: p(s(p(p(0)))) would be p(p(0))? Why not -2?

Comment: p(p(0)) is the same as -2 but I have to use this method of counting.

Comment: Then why did you say that p(0) is -1? 'p(0)' must stay as 'p(0)', right?

Comment: Do you have any attempts at code for this? Also, wouldn't `simplify(s(p(s(0))), Z)` result in `Z = s(0)` not `Z = s`?

Comment: p(0) is equivalent to -1 but must stay as p(0). And you are right lurker, Z=s(0) not just s. I have updated the code.

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: I didn't ask the question as I thought it was obvious. I was looking for some pointers or advice.

Answer (score 2):

```
z(0).
z(s(X)) :-
   z(X).
z(p(X)) :-
   z(X).

z_canonized(Z, C) :-
   z_canonized(Z, 0, C).

z_canonized(0, C,C).
z_canonized(s(N), C0,C) :-
   z_succ(C0,C1),
   z_canonized(N, C1,C).
z_canonized(p(N), C0,C) :-
   z_pred(C0,C1),
   z_canonized(N, C1,C).

z_succ(0,s(0)).
z_succ(s(X),s(s(X))). % was: z_succ(X,s(X)) :- ( X = 0 ; X = s(_) ).
z_succ(p(X),X).

z_pred(0,p(0)).
z_pred(p(X),p(p(X))).
z_pred(s(X),X).
```

Answer (score 2):

My attempt:

```
simplify(X, Z) :-
    simplify(X, 0, Z).
simplify(0, Z, Z).
simplify(s(X), 0, Z) :- simplify(X, s(0), Z).
simplify(p(X), 0, Z) :- simplify(X, p(0), Z).
simplify(p(X), s(Y), Z) :- simplify(X, Y, Z).
simplify(s(X), p(Y), Z) :- simplify(X, Y, Z).
simplify(s(X), s(Y), Z) :- simplify(X, s(s(Y)), Z).
simplify(p(X), p(Y), Z) :- simplify(X, p(p(Y)), Z).
```

*Update* - shorter version:

```
simplify(X, Z) :-
    simplify(X, 0, Z).
simplify(0, Z, Z).
simplify(p(X), s(Y), Z) :- simplify(X, Y, Z).
simplify(s(X), p(Y), Z) :- simplify(X, Y, Z).
simplify(s(X), Y, Z) :- Y \= p(_), simplify(X, s(Y), Z).
simplify(p(X), Y, Z) :- Y \= s(_), simplify(X, p(Y), Z).
```

Some tests:

```
?- simplify(s(p(s(0))), Z).
Z = s(0) 

?- simplify(p(s(p(p(0)))), Z).
Z = p(p(0)) 

?- simplify(p(p(s(s(0)))), Z).
Z = 0
```

Comment: Rare case where `(\=)/2` does not interfere with declarative properties.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another answer, coded for fun of it. It first simplifies an expression into an integer and then converts the result into `p(...)` for negative integers, `s(...)` for positive integers (excluding zero), and `0` for `0`. The standard `sign/1` arithmetic function is used to take advantage of first-argument indexing.

```
simplify(Expression, Result) :-
    simplify(Expression, 0, Result0),
    Sign is sign(Result0),
    convert(Sign, Result0, Result).

simplify(0, Result, Result).
simplify(s(X), Result0, Result) :-
    Result1 is Result0 + 1,
    simplify(X, Result1, Result).
simplify(p(X), Result0, Result) :-
    Result1 is Result0 - 1,
    simplify(X, Result1, Result).

convert(-1, N, p(Result)) :-
    N2 is N + 1,
    Sign is sign(N2),
    convert(Sign, N2, Result).
convert(0, _, 0).
convert(1, N, s(Result)) :-
    N2 is N - 1,
    Sign is sign(N2),
    convert(Sign, N2, Result).
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, another "fun" solution. This one works in [ECliPSe](http://eclipseclp.org) and uses non-standard `append_strings`, which is a strings' analog of lists' `append`:

```
simplify(X, Z) :-
    term_string(X, Xstr),
    ( append_strings(Middle, End, Xstr), 
        ( 
            append_strings(Begin, "s(p(", Middle) 
        ; 
            append_strings(Begin, "p(s(", Middle) 
        ) ->
        append_strings(NewEnd, "))", End),
        append_strings(Begin, NewEnd, Zstr),
        term_string(Ztemp, Zstr),
        simplify(Ztemp, Z)
    ;
      Z = X
    ).
```

Comment: +1 There's always room for a mind-warping solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is my answer:

```
simplify(X, Z) :- simplify(X, 0, 0, Z).
simplify(0, 0, X, X).
simplify(0, X, 0, X) :- X \= 0.
simplify(0, p(X), s(Y), Z) :- simplify(0, X, Y, Z).
simplify(p(X), P, S, Z) :- simplify(X, p(P), S, Z).
simplify(s(X), P, S, Z) :- simplify(X, P, s(S), Z).
```

I'm dividing input structure into two chains of `p`s and `s`s and then I am removing one by one from both chains. When one of them ends, the other one becomes the result of operation. I think it is quite efficient.

Comment: @false, what do you mean?

Comment: `simplify(s(p(0)),S).` gives two answers. So there is a redundant solution `S = 0`.

Comment: @False, OK, instead of cuts I'm checking if `X \= 0` in one of cases.

Answer (score 0):

I was inspired by Paulo's submission to do a variant of the "Count the p's and s's" approach:

```
simplify(Exp, Simp) :-
    exp_count(Exp, Count),
    exp_count(Simp, Count).

exp_count(Exp, C) :-
    exp_count(Exp, 0, C).

exp_count(s(X), A, C) :-
    (   nonvar(C)
    ->  A < C
    ;   true
    ),
    A1 is A + 1,
    exp_count(X, A1, C).
exp_count(p(X), A, C) :-
    (   nonvar(C)
    ->  A > C
    ;   true
    ),
    A1 is A - 1,
    exp_count(X, A1, C).
exp_count(0, C, C).
```

Comment: The only issue I found in your solution is that it leaves spurious choice-points (introduced by the the second call to `exp_count/2` by `simplify/2`).

Comment: @PauloMoura yes. `exp_count/2` is trying hard to be a relational predicate, but isn't quite there. My original intent was to try and get it to be relational, and then do a cut upon first yielding the "all `s`" or "all `p`" solution. It's imperfect as it is. So I only offered this as an interesting variant, but not an optimal solution.